# How do I provide context to terminologies in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, autodesk-forge

The IDE does not recognize some terminology as being in context with my code. Could I employ quotes ""?

This code is for an OSS controller. When I add quotes to the term, the IDE accepts it. If I do not use quotes, there appears to be an error.

```
    {
      nodes.Add(new TreeNode(bucket.Value.bucketKey, bucket.Value.bucketKey.Replace(ClientId + "-", string.Empty), "bucket", true));
    }

{
  BucketsApi buckets = new BucketsApi();
  dynamic token = await OAuthController.GetInternalAsync();
  buckets.Configuration.AccessToken = token.access_token;
  PostBucketsPayload bucketPayload = new PostBucketsPayload(string.Format("{0}-{1}", ClientId, bucket.bucketKey.ToLower()), null,
    PostBucketsPayload.PolicyKeyEnum.Transient);
  return await buckets.CreateBucketAsync(bucketPayload, "US");
}
```

This way, the IDE does not recognize ClientID as being in context with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems you found a problem on the tutorial, kudos! It's missing one line at the beginning, see the [entire code](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/blob/net/forgesample/Controllers/OSSController.cs#L31) here for your reference. It's now fixed, please refresh the tutorial page.

Here is the missing line:

```
public string ClientId { get { return OAuthController.GetAppSetting("FORGE_CLIENT_ID").ToLower(); } }
```